# Why am I unable to scroll down the page using Selenium 2?

Tags: java, selenium

I have gecko driver installed already.
I am little bit confused in page scroll down.Console is not showing me any error as I have written Test Case failed if (if condition fails):

```
package PackageQandle;

//import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

//import junit.framework.Assert;

public class Adduser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable  {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/Users/sudhir/geckodriver-v0.18.0-win32/geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://prod4.qandle.com");
        WebDriverWait webwait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120);
        webwait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='login-email']")));
        WebElement web = driver.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='login-email']");
        web.sendKeys("Anil@gmail.com");
        WebDriverWait webwait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        webwait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='login-password']")));
        WebElement web1 = driver.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='login-password']");
        web1.sendKeys("Abc12345");
        WebElement web2 = driver.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='signInSubmit']");
        web2.submit();

        //Assert.assertEquals(my_Title, my_ExpectedTitle);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        //JavascriptExecutor j = new JavascriptExecutor();
        String my_Title = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        //System.out.println(my_Title);
        String my_ExpectedTitle = "https://prod4.qandle.com/#/";

        if(my_Title.equals(my_ExpectedTitle)){
             driver.executeScript("Scroll(0,600);");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Test Case Failed");

        }

    }

}
```

I am using this code to inspect element which appears when I scroll down the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast driver to JavascriptExecutor type

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) deiver;
WebElement scrollElement = driver.findElement();
jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scrollElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax of findElementByXpath must be

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-password']"));

Try the below mentioned code for scrolling to element, it worked for me

```
   driver.get("https://prod4.qandle.com");
  WebDriverWait webwait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120);

  webwait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-email']"))));
  WebElement web = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-email']"));
  web.sendKeys("Anil@gmail.com");
  WebDriverWait webwait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
  webwait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-password']"))));
  WebElement web1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-password']"));
  web1.sendKeys("Abc12345");
  WebElement web2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signInSubmit']"));
  web2.submit();

  //Assert.assertEquals(my_Title, my_ExpectedTitle);
  try {
Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  String my_Title = driver.getCurrentUrl();
  String my_ExpectedTitle = "https://prod4.qandle.com/#/";

  if(my_Title.equals(my_ExpectedTitle)){
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
   // Mention the xpath of the element to be scrolled for
       WebElement tempElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Reports')]"));


      ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", tempElement);
  }else{
      System.out.println("Test Case Failed");

  }
```

Comment: But as you seen my code..is there any mistake if i follow only my code..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "Chrome" use:

```
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(true);", e)
```

For "Firefox" and "IE" use:

```
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);" +
                                     "window.scrollBy(0,-100);", e);
```